# Making a Tasks Tree

Tags: java, tree, scheduled-tasks, distributed

Is it possible for me to create a tree of objects in which it's holding Strings. For instance, as shown below

```
         T1
         |
         T2
         /\
        T3 T4
         \ /
          T5
```

What's the syntax to creating such tree? I'm trying to make it so that each run on sequence,parallel, and nesting order.

this is what I've written thus far:

```
    public class Tasks {
    public Node node;
    public String put(String value, int[] path){

    Node current = node;

    for(int i=0;i<path.length;i++){
        if(current.children.get(i)==null){
            current.children.add(i, new Node());
        }
        current = current.children.get(i);
    }
    String ret = current.value;
    current.value = value;

   Tasks myTask = new Tasks();
    myTask.node = new Node();
    int[] path1 = {0, 0, 0};
    myTask.put("T1", path1);
    System.out.println(myTask.get(path1));
}

 }

public class Node{
public ArrayList<Node> children;
public Node parent;
public String value;
```

}

Comment: With what exactly are you having trouble with? How to make classes?  How to Instantiate them and reference each other?

Comment: What you have drawn is technically not a Tree. It is possible to represent it using notation similar to a Tree.

Comment: The feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  Why are you trying to create this structure? What are the objects you need to store? You say you are trying to make it so that `each run on sequence, parallel and nesting order` - each what?  Take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for hints on writing a better question.  The more information you can give, the more help you will get.

Comment: I apologize if I sounded vague at all. What I'm trying to do is make each task perform some sort of computation in a scheduled manner, concurrently, paralleled, and finally nested. String is what each task will be holding.  "How to Instantiate them and reference each other? " Yes!.....

Comment: Your question make it look like you want to implement a data structure, but if I'm not mistaken, you want to organize some tasks or threads according to your diagram?

Comment: Yes, I want to organize those 5 tasks to work in an organized manner as shown above. Can that be achieved in making some sort of an object tree?  Also, I want it so that T2 would know that T1 is its parent and T3 and T4 are children of T2...etc.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to make that clearer, like "I want to organize tasks like this tree...", etc.
Also, if you want to notify to someone that you have answered his comment, try using the @ feature in your comment (for example: @AlexisLeclerc) :)

Comment: I could imagine some solution with executors. But first: Do you have already some code to start with?

Comment: Yes. I'll be posting when I get home. Thanks for the hhint,I was thinking something like a task scheduler .

Comment: Okay, this is what I've written thus far, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. The code below is me trying to construct a tree and connecting the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this example using an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) tasks organized according to your given tree structure. It's ready to run, so you can test it and experiment with it:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Declare a new ExecutorService with a maximum of 2 threads.
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        // Declare the tasks.
        StringTask t1 = new StringTask("First task!");
        StringTask t2 = new StringTask("Second task!");
        StringTask t3 = new StringTask("Third task!");
        StringTask t4 = new StringTask("Fourth task!");
        StringTask t5 = new StringTask("Fifth task!");

        // Submit the first task.
        String result1 = service.submit(t1).get(); // Using the .get() directly blocks the waiting for completion of the task.
        System.out.println("T1 result: " + result1);

        // Submit the second task.
        String result2 = service.submit(t2).get();
        System.out.println("T2 result: " + result2);

        // Prepare the list of parallel tasks and invoke them.
        List<StringTask> parallelTasks = new ArrayList<>(2);
        parallelTasks.add(t3);
        parallelTasks.add(t4);
        List<Future<String>> results = service.invokeAll(parallelTasks); // Note that using .invokeAll() will block the
                                                                         // execution until all tasks are completed.
        for (Future<String> result : results) {
            System.out.println("Parallel task result: " + result.get());
        }

        // Submit the last task.
        String result5 = service.submit(t5).get();
        System.out.println("T5 result: " + result5);
    }

    /**
     * Callable task that reverses a given String.
     */
    private static final class StringTask implements Callable<String> {
        private String input;

        private StringTask(String input) {
            super();

            if (input == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }

            this.input = input;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = this.input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                builder.append(this.input.charAt(i));
            }

            return builder.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

If you know in advance the tasks and how they're organized, you can *hardcode* them in a similar manner. However, if the task structure is not static or not known in advance, you might want to implement your own task tree structure (with `CallableNode` objects for example) and use an `ExecutorService` to go through that tree and execute the tasks according to its structure.

Comment: Thanks!
I've started working with that approach. I'll update you soon!

Comment: @Christy Don't forget that you can tweak the class that implements `Callable` (or even create different ones) to better suit your needs. Mine was only a simple example!